# Pg-promise client doesn't retrieve special characters properly from ElephantSQL cloud database

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, special-characters, pg-promise

I'm currently coding an API that connects to an ElephantSQL instance using `pg-promise`. Everything works fine except that special characters from text columns (like accented letters) are not retrieved properly (i.e. the word "Collège" shows as "CollÃ¨ge" in the JSON object). I suppose this has something to do with the encoding, but special characters are displayed properly in ElephantSQL's dashboard, so I don't think the database encoding is wrong - though I can't find any information about the database encoding in the first place. So my best guess is, I need to add something to the client to specify the encoding I wish to get the results in. I have tried tweaking the `client_encoding` as described in [this page](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/906), using `utf8` and `latin1`, but to no avail. Is there something I'm missing or did I just try the wrong encodings?

**UPDATE**

When running the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.character_sets;
```

I get the following JSON object:

```
{
character_set_catalog: null,
character_set_schema: null,
character_set_name: "UTF8",
character_repertoire: "UCS",
form_of_use: "UTF8",
default_collate_catalog: "ggnonllb",
default_collate_schema: null,
default_collate_name: null
}
```

So I know for a fact that my online DB is encoded in UTF8 (as one would expect). But my issue isn't solved even though every query I run is wrapped inside a `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';`. So I feel awfully confused. It's as though this had nothing to do with characters encoding. But why would the pg-promise client get results with special characters scrambled if it's not a matter of characters encoding? Moreover, this only happens when retrieving data, not when posting them, since the special characters show as they should in the ElephantSQL's dashboard.

Comment: I just ran a test with pg-promise v9.0.0, by doing first `insert into french(message) values('Collège')`, then then `select * from french`, and i'm seeing exactly what was expected. What versions of pg-promise and PostgreSQL are you using? Maybe it is an issue with ElephantSQL.

Comment: I'm using pg-promise v9.0.0. As to PostgreSQL, I don't actually have a version installed, since I'm using ElephantSQL - I query the cloud database directly.

Perhaps it's worth noting that changing the client encoding sometimes returns a different "scrambling" of special characters (they still don't show properly, but not in the same way), so I guess I'm on the right track, but I couldn't find a single encoding that gives me the desired output.

Comment: As per that issue example, does it help wrapping the request inside `SET client_encoding to 'latin1';`? You would use a task with pg-promise for this.

Comment: That's what I tried, actually all my queries run through a function that automatically wraps them in `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`(or `ROLLBACK` on error), and I added `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'latin1';`(or utf8 or others) to the wrapping as well. That's when the different scrambling occurs.

Comment: If even after wrapping into that encoding SQL it still doesn't work, then the issue isn't with `pg-promise`, it is elsewhere. This is as far as I can help though.

Comment: @vitaly-t I updated my question with some new piece of information. Thank you in advance for reviewing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. Seems like it was a problem with the character encoding of the response. When I query my API from my browser, the special characters still don't show like they should, but when called from my application, all is fine.

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected, that you were losing the encoding in some mid-layer, and that it had nothing to do with the database.